# ngx-boostrap in angular2 creating duplicative tabs each time a new tab is dynamically created after button click?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I want to use tabs in ngx-boostrap. I am using the following dynamic tabs example:

http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/

My code in my template:

```
<button ng-click="addTab()">Add Tab</button>
<tabset>
  <tab *ngFor="let tabz of mytabs" [heading]="tabz.title"></tab>
</tabset>       


let mytabs = [];
addTab() {
mytabs.push({title: 'Tab 1'})
}
```

Issue is when I click on "addTab()" I should get 3 tabs wtih 'Tab 1', but I am instead getting 1 tab with the first click, 2 new tabs the second click, and 3 new tabs the 4th click. (meaning I have a total of 6 tabs after clicking the only 3 times. How do I resolve this? If I click on the button 3 times, I should only get 3 tabs. When I log out the array each time I click the button, I see mytabs has the correct amount of items (3), but on display, there are 6 tabs after clicking 3 times.

If this is something that is not possible to get around, is there any 'tabs' component that works with angular2 that allows me to dynamically add tabs and content similar to the method I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in ng2-bootstrap/tabs. It is already fixed in [#1941](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/pull/1941) and in version [v1.7.1](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/releases/tag/v1.7.1)